# Trying to get property of non-object in middleware - laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have this middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $user = $this->auth->getUser(); 
    if ($user->role_id == 1) {
        return $response;
    } else {
        return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
    }
}
```

i want to use this middleware when call profile page and the code in route is:

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'superAdmin', 'uses' => 'users\UserController@index']);
```

and I added it to $routeMiddleware array in kernel.php

when call the page:

```
http://localhost:8080/public/profile
```

got this error:

```
ErrorException in SuperAdminRoleMiddleware.php line 43: Trying to get property of non-object
```

line 43 is: if ($user->role_id == 1) {

what is the issue:

Comment: Where are you getting `$this->auth->getUser()` from? The Auth class in Laravel provides `Auth::user()`

Comment: I have already included Auth at top of file - use Auth;

Comment: That still doesn't explain where $this->auth->getUser() comes from.

Comment: I am using it in another middleware and works fine it is a method in auth class.

Comment: in this middleware works fine   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $user = $this->auth->getUser(); 

        if ($user->status == 1) {
            return Redirect::to('/home');
        } else {
         Auth::logout();
         return Redirect::to('/auth/login')->withInput($request->only('username', 'remember'))
                 ->withErrors([
                     'username' => 'Your account still NOT active',
                 ]);
        }

        return $response;

    }

Comment: `var_dump($user)` - what value does it hold?

Comment: $user object is null

Comment: Then figure out why `$this->auth->getUser()` returns `null`. If necessary rephrase your question into this direction.

Comment: but i used another middleware like this and it's work, may be somthing not included

Comment: this middleware (status) works fine:  Route::post('/auth/login', ['middleware' => 'status', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin']);

Comment: Post the entire middleware so we can see what's happening

Comment: "It works just fine elsewhere" is not helping anyone solve this. It doesn't work *here*, figure out why.